# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb02' in position 582: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

job_title = []
company_name = []
location_name = []
job_skill = []
links = []
salary = []
requirements = []
date = []
page_num = 0
while page_num != 20:

    result = requests.get(f"https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=web%20development&start={page_num}")
    source = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

    job_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"class", "jcs-JobTitle"})
    company_names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "companyName"})
    location_names = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "companyLocation"})
    job_skills = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "job-snippet"})
    dates = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "date"})

    for i in range(len(job_titles)):
        job_title.append(job_titles[i].text.strip())
        links.append("https://www.indeed.com" + job_titles[i].attrs["href"])
        company_name.append(company_names[i].text.strip())
        location_name.append(location_names[i].text.strip())
        job_skill.append(job_skills[i].text.strip())
        date.append(dates[i].text.strip())

    page_num += 10
    print("Page switched...")

for link in links:
    result = requests.get(link)
    source = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    salaries = soup.find("span", {"class": "icl-u-xs-mr--xs attribute_snippet"})
    salary.append(salaries.text if salaries else "None".strip())
    requirement = soup.find("div", {"id": "jobDescriptionText", "class": "jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"}).ul
    requirements_text = ""
    if requirement:
        for li in requirement.find_all("li"):
            requirements_text += li.text + "| "
    else:
        requirements_text += "None"
    requirements_text = requirements_text[:-2]
    requirements.append(requirements_text)


my_file = [job_title, company_name, location_name, job_skill, salary, links, date, requirements]
exported = zip_longest(*my_file)
with open("/Users/Rich/Desktop/testing/indeed.csv", "w") as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(["Job titles", "Company names", "Location names", "Job skills", "Salaries", "Links", "Dates", "Requirements"])
    writer.writerows(exported)
```

i was scraping multiple pages in a website and everythin working well till i added the requirements list to the csv file, if i remove the requirements it works fine.
i get this error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb02' in position 582: character maps to 
please help me

Comment: Works OK for me in my mac, i only changed this two lines soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser"). I am using python 3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding: `encoding="utf-8"` to the csv file...
the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

job_title = []
company_name = []
location_name = []
job_skill = []
links = []
salary = []
requirements = []
date = []
page_num = 0
num = 1
while page_num != 5000:

    result = requests.get(f"https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=web%20development&start={page_num}")
    source = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

    job_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"class", "jcs-JobTitle"})
    company_names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "companyName"})
    location_names = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "companyLocation"})
    job_skills = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "job-snippet"})
    dates = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "date"})

    for i in range(len(job_titles)):
        job_title.append(job_titles[i].text.strip())
        links.append("https://www.indeed.com" + job_titles[i].attrs["href"])
        company_name.append(company_names[i].text.strip())
        location_name.append(location_names[i].text.strip())
        job_skill.append(job_skills[i].text.strip())
        date.append(dates[i].text.strip())

    page_num += 10
    print(f"{num}.Page switched...")
    num += 1

for link in links:
    result = requests.get(link)
    source = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    salaries = soup.find("span", {"class": "icl-u-xs-mr--xs attribute_snippet"})
    salary.append(salaries.text if salaries else "None".strip())
    requirement = soup.find("div", {"id": "jobDescriptionText", "class": "jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"}).ul
    requirements_text = ""
    if requirement:
        for li in requirement.find_all("li"):
            requirements_text += li.text.strip() + "| "
    else:
        requirements_text += "None"
    requirements_text = requirements_text[:-2]
    requirements.append(requirements_text)


my_file = [job_title, company_name, location_name, job_skill, salary, links, date, requirements]
exported = zip_longest(*my_file)
with open("/Users/Rich/Desktop/testing/indeed.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(["Job titles", "Company names", "Location names", "Job skills", "Salaries", "Links", "Dates", "Requirements"])
    writer.writerows(exported)
```

but I don't know what `encoding="utf-8"` is for, any idea ??